# Deriving a simple inequality in the context of a linear model.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming

Somewhat of a basic derivation, yet I am somehow stuck. Let us have the linear model,
\begin{equation}
y=X\theta+w
\end{equation}
where $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the response variable, $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ is a random design matrix, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is a $d\times 1$ vector of unknown parameters, and $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a noise vector.  Suppose $\theta^*$ is the true value of this vector of parameters, and $\hat{\theta}$ is the optimal solution. Further, take the inequality $\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-X\hat{\theta}\rVert_2^2\leq\frac{1}{2n}\lVert y-X\theta^*\rVert_2^2$, and denote $\hat{\Delta}:=\hat{\theta}-\theta^*$. Show that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lVert X\hat{\Delta}\rVert_2^2}{n}\leq\frac{2w'X\hat{\Delta}}{n}
\end{equation}

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel the $\frac{1}{2n}$ on both sides and set $y = X \theta^* + w$ in the norms. You get

$$
\| X(\theta^* - \hat{\theta}) + w \|_2^2 \leq \| w\|_2^2
$$

Open up the norm on the left:

$$
\| X(\theta^* - \hat{\theta}) \|_2^2 + \| w \|_2^2 + 2 w^{\mathsf{T}} X(\theta^* - \hat{\theta}) \leq \| w \|_2^2 \Leftrightarrow
\| X(\theta^* - \hat{\theta})\|_2^2 \leq 2 w^{\mathsf{T}}X(\hat{\theta} - \theta^*).
$$

This is precisely the given inequality.